# When to use the different words that mean to use or put on clothing? veste/ calçamos / usa / visto / bota

Tags: significado, vocabulário, diferenças-transatlânticas

I learned Portuguese from Portugal. Now doing the Duolingo Portuguese course, it is heavily influenced by Brazil.

I am getting destroyed by the lessons that deal with clothing. I always get the 'to dress / to wear' verb wrong.

How can I know when it is appropriate to use *vestir* vs *calçar* vs *usar*?

Comment: Sorry Joshua, that's a common difficulty. They're 190 million, we are 10 million... of course the majority of resources are in pt-BR and not pt-PT.

Comment: For levels B1-B2 of pt-PT, I personally recommend the work book "As Cidades do Mar" by Porto Editora: https://www.portoeditora.pt/ensino-portugues-no-estrangeiro/projetos/cidadesdomar

Comment: Frankly, I think these uses are probably the same on both sides of the Atlantic., except maybe botar. They might use por, instead: por um vestido, por os sapatos. etc.

Comment: Whoever is trolling through my answers and dving me should take a hard look at themselves.

Comment: I have come back to this a year later and I can't understand why my perfectly good answer, in this case, maybe great, was downvoted.

Answer (score 6):

I am Brazilian from São Paulo. I say it because I have the impression that this may change from place to place, even only inside Brazil.

Basically, the word *vestir* means to dress; ex.: *eu vou vestir um vestido lindíssimo!* = *I'll dress a very beautiful dress*. As in English, one can dress a baby: *Vesti o bebê pro inverno* = *I dressed the baby for the winter*. The verb *vestir* can also be pronominal if with no object: *Ele se vestiram bem* = *They dressed (up) well*. I believe one could say *eles vestiram bem*, but it sounds weird, at least for me, unless there's an object omitted. The verb has other meanings, but that's the basics and the other meanings are similar or figurative. Two notes: the verb is irregular in the present of the first person singular indicative: *visto* instead of *vesto*; also in the present of the subjunctive: *vista*, *vistas*, *vistamos*, *vistais* and *vistam*. The second note is that one doesn't *veste* a shoe or a sock.

The word *calçar* means to put on. According to the dictionary, one can *calçar* trousers or gloves, but I have only seen it being used for things put on one's foot/feet, like a shoe or a boot and maybe socks. As with *vestir*, one can *calçar* someone; ex.: *só preciso calçar o meu filho e já vamos* = *I just need to put the shoes on my son, and then we go*. Idem, it can be pronominal: *Você se calçou bem* = *You put on (some) good shoes* (non-literal translation). Interesting that you can say “calça o cone” or “calça o *slime*”.

The word *usar* means to use; for clothes, one could translate it to *have on*; ex.: *eu vou usar aquela camisa que cê me deu na festa amanhã* = *I'll use that shirt you gave me in the party tomorrow*, *Eu 'to' usando uma camisa da minha avó* = *I have on a shirt of my grandmother*.

To summarize: *vestir* is irregualar and means to dress, *calçar* means to put a thing on your foot, and *usar* means to have on or to use.

Comment: That's exactly how I use these words too.

Comment: In Portugal, "calçar" is also for gloves. "Calçar umas luvas" is idiomatic. We may also use "pôr umas luvas", "vestir umas luvas", and other similar constructs; but gloves are used with verb "calçar".

Comment: (Shouldn't "calçar" be for "calças" (pants)?!?!???? Never try to make sense about languages, you'll go insane!)

Comment: I have to laugh (nicely): calçar means to put a thing on your foot. Isn't that: botar uma coisa no pé? They were well dressed. ou seja: Eles estavam bem vestidos.

Comment: Porque que você vai vestir un vestido lindo? Será que vestir un terno lindo não seria melhor? :)

Comment: one can calçar trousers ?? Trousers can be calças, more like.

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy [for me to explain]:
That is not condescending at all. Isn't it nice when something is easy?

**Vestir** roupa = wear or put on **clothes** or dress, [visto x: I wear x.]
**Calçar** sapatos = wear or put on **shoes**.  [for footwear]
These are used when discussing sizes worn: Visto um (tamanho) 36. Calço um (tamanho) 42.
What size do you wear? [**shoes**] Que tamanho você **calça**?
What size do you wear [**clothes**] Que tamanho você **veste**?

Visto is the simple present: I wear or put on some item of clothing.

Please note: **both those can be *wear* in English**, but you should not confuse the ones for shoes and the one for clothes. If you can remember that sidewalk is Calçada, where you walk, that should help you remember: calçar sapatos.

**Usar**= to wear; shoes, clothes, jewelry, watches, hats, etc.

- Uso calça comprida no trabalho.
- I wear long pants at work.
- Já não uso relogio. [I no longer wear a watch.]

Usar is used for something worn regularly. To be worn.

- Do you wear a hat everyday? Você usa chapéu todos os dias?

You will have to learn the verbs by heart: vestir, calçar, usar, botar.

The good news: four verbs with an AR ending, and one with an IR ending. **You can look up those conjugations and tenses, I am not putting them all up here.**

The verb vestir is only irregular in the first person singular, present tense: Eu visto. (That makes the subjunctive be: vista, as subjunctives comes from that tense and person. But that's quite advanced.)

Special note about botar: botar should be used like this:  He **put on** his flips flops when he went to the beach. (Ele botou as havianas quando foi à praia.)

Botar can be used in the sense of PUT ON.

- Put on your shoes right now. Bota os sapatos agora mesmo.

Vestir and botar both mean to put on. But vestir is more formal and botar is more informal and used in the sense of: PUT ON for a purpose.

- He **dresses** very well. Ele **se veste** muito bem.
- He **puts on** a coat when its cold. Ele **bota** ou **veste** um casaco quando faz frio.

Finally, instead of botar, you can use por for put on, but the verb por is highly irregular.

Eu nunca ponho havaianas em casa. I never put on flip flops at home.

[This is perhaps not the full story, but it is at least half of it].

Comment: -1: "*This is really easy*" feels condescendent, and I feel like this topic should feel confusing to someone who's not native in Portuguese (although I am); your explanations of the verbs `usar` and `botar` are too generic and very confusing; also bad formatting, e.g. bulleted list first brings an example, then next item is translation of item above, then third item is another example with translation in brackets (bad for readability).

Comment: @GuiImamura The term is condescend*ing*. That is your opinion. If I say something is easy, it means easy to explain. usar and botar are not "too generic" when they mean vestir. They are a different **register**; they're informal.

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't know how to use that word. About that being my opinion: Yes it is, but I uv/dv according to my opinion, and that might have been the opinion of others also; I felt like I should comment since you commented you didn't understand why anyone would dv *your perfectly good answer*.

Comment: It is a perfectly good answer.

Comment: Okay. I just **hate** to have my questions/answers downvoted and have no feedback at all, so I thought you might want to hear my opinion; between having no feedback at all, and someone leaving a comment about *what they believe the problem in my question/answer is*, I absolutely prefer the latter even if they are rude, mean or condescending. If you don't want further opinions, you just shouldn't ask for them.